# "Unable to resolve resource bundle" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: flash, apache-flex, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up IDEA (14.1.4) to compile [GrindPlayer](http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/docs/grind/), but I'm getting stuck with the following error:

```
Error:[GrindPlayer]: Unable to resolve resource bundle "Main".
```

In the `GrindPlayer.mxml` file there is the following entry:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("Main")]
</fx:Metadata>
```

The resource files are in the `locale` directories:

[image]

The source folders have been marked:

[image]

I already added the libraries I could find in the module dependencies:

[image]

The build call from the Makefile is the following, and it works when I run it on the commandline:

```
/opt/apache-flex-413-102/bin/mxmlc -o build/GrindPlayer.swf \
    -debug=true \
    -locale=en_US,ru_RU \
    -swf-version=11 \
    -target-player=10.2 \
    -default-size=640,360 \
    -default-background-color=0 \
    -sp src locale/{locale} \
    -l "/opt/apache-flex-413-102/frameworks/libs" "/opt/apache-flex-413-102/frameworks/locale/{locale}" \
    -l libs "build/libs" \
    -externs ru.kutu.osmf.advertisement.AdvertisementPlugin \
    -externs ru.kutu.osmf.subtitles.SubtitlesPlugin \
    -define CONFIG::HLS false \
    -define CONFIG::DEV true \
    src/GrindPlayer.mxml \
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of downvoting without a comment, it would've been nice to tell me what exactly is missing from the question so that I can add it.

Comment: Very nicely formatted and detailed question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add
-source-path=locale/{locale}
in you compiler arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark **ru_RU**, **en_US** folders as sources instead of **locale**.

Comment: Thanks. Will try when I'm back at the computer on Monday. But doesn't the small blue dot in the `ru_RU` and `en_US` folders mean they're… inherited as source folders? But I'll check.

Comment: Seems, they should be the root source. At least they are when you compile via commandline -sp src locale/{locale}

Answer (score 0):

try 
to add "/opt/apache-flex-413-102/frameworks/locale/{locale}" to your source path instead of "locale/{locale}"